# First all zero row of a matrix in C++

Tags: c++, functional-programming, c++14, iterator

The problem of finding the first all zero row in a NxN matrix was featured in a [letter to the CACM in 1974 by Frank Rubin](http://web.archive.org/web/20090320002214/http://www.ecn.purdue.edu/ParaMount/papers/rubin87goto.pdf) who claimed it was a problem for which using a `GOTO` was better than alternatives.

But many languages have labeled break statements and other features that make the problem trivial. In fact, in JavaScript we need only write:

```
a.findIndex(row => row.every(x => x === 0))
```

which gives us the index of the first nonzero row or -1 if no such row exists. I'm interested in implementing this functional approach in C++ 14. As I don't have a huge amount of C++ experience, I came up with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

bool isAllZeroRow(const vector<int>& row) {
  return all_of(row.begin(), row.end(), [](int x){return x==0;});
}

int firstAllZeroIndex(const vector<vector<int>>& m) {
  return distance(m.begin(), find_if(m.begin(), m.end(), isAllZeroRow));
}

vector<vector<int>> matrix1 = {{1, 2}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}};
vector<vector<int>> matrix2 = {{0, 0, 1, 2}, {3, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}};
vector<vector<int>> matrix3 = {{0, 0, 1, 2}, {3, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 5}};

int main() {
  assert(firstAllZeroIndex(matrix1) == 1);
  assert(firstAllZeroIndex(matrix2) == 2);
  assert(firstAllZeroIndex(matrix3) == 3); // not found
  cout << "ok\n";
}
```

I'm interested in hearing things like:

- whether the lambda is okay, or should it be a named function or a C++ unary predicat
- Are `distance` and `find_if` best expressed with iterators like I have done here?
- Was it right to use the helper function, or is there a way in C++ to make things almost as concise as the JavaScript solution?

I know how to do this function with nested loops with a `return` in the inner loop, but I'm intrigued by trying out the functional forms and was wondering how I did.

Comment: not sure what you are after. the "lambda is okay", "best expressed with iterators" and "was it right" questions are missing prerequisites. what are your requirements?

Comment: The question is finding "First all zero row ", why do you scan row and column?

Comment: @andreas Right, great questions, I meant lambdas vs. things like unary_functions and predicates from `<functional>`. and iterators vs. collection-specific methods, if any. Only "requirements" are to employ the most idiomatic uses of the standard library possible.

Comment: @phynju Is there a way to determine if a row contains all zeros without "scanning the columns"? I think `all_of` is perfectly safe; it returns as soon as it finds an element not meeting the condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### avoid importing namespaces

You have `using namespace std;`. You are obviously working in a `.cpp` where it is usually fine to do this; but I (and many others) don't like to remove the `std::`. It is short enough to write it every time you are trying to access a function/class or whatever of the `std` scope. Use it; it makes things clearer (at least for me ;))

### use free functions over member functions

Herb Sutter described it nice in one of his articles; please forgive me that I am not able to provide you with a short text but on stackoverflow there are plenty of topics like this.
E.g. [click me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452130/when-to-use-stdbegin-and-stdend-instead-of-container-specific-versions)

It is more generic to use the `std::begin` and `std::end` functions than the container specific one. Technically it is totally the same; it just makes it easier to change the container type.

### keep things local

I think you know that you should keep your objects as local as possible. I don't see a good reason here to declare your matrix objects in the global scope.

### lambdas

The lambdas are fine. You could use a lambda for the `isAllZeroRow()` function instead of declaring a free function for this, but this is also fine.

You can declare the lambda parameters as `auto`. You don't have to define types explicitly anymore. This safes us from some annoying typing and redundancy and - one of my most loved arguments - it's more generic.

You could also delete the other free function, too, and just create a local lambda object.

```
int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix1 = {{1, 2}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}};

    auto firstAllZeroIndex = [](const auto& m) {
        return std::distance(std::begin(m), std::find_if(std::begin(m), std::end(m), [](const auto& row){
            return std::all_of(std::begin(row), std::end(row), [](int x){return x==0;});
        }));
    };
    assert(firstAllZeroIndex(matrix1) == 1);
}
```

### more meaningful return type

You should use a return type which offers you the possibility to return an invalid statement. In c++17 we'll get the comfortable type `std::optional`, but for now we can use a `std::pair<int, bool>` statement. In this case, the `int` of the type has a valid value as long as the `bool` of the pair is true. I recommend this, because it makes the code more self-descriptive.

### some praises

You are using the c++ headers; `<cassert>` is the right one, as every other header with the `c` prefix and without the `.h`. Good job :D

From my point of view your solution looks almost perfect (at least with the given requirements). You should be aware of the fact, that in this example you could use `std::array` types instead of `std::vector` and that it could be possible to resize your matrix objects which could lead to different row sizes in one matrix object. In the end I would write a class for this, to prevent me (and others) from doing such dumb stuff and getting frustrated ;)

Comment: Much appreciated feedback - I should use explicit `std::` and `auto` more often indeed!  (And yeah the test cases could have been in `main` :) ) Oh and also, having optionals would have been nice; I've been doing this in a lot of languages and it looks _very_ good in Elm and Haskell with `Maybe`!